# Posts being loaded for all users in collection view firebase & swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All I'm trying to do is fetch all the posts to the collection view that are within a certain radius of the current user. Currently I'm getting all the current users posts within the location but that is all. I can't figure out how to convert it to fetch all the posts from all the users.

`FetchPostUserIds` Is returning a snapshot of all the users and there `UID`

The geoFire query is only returning the `postId` from the current user. It shouldn't be I assume

**Note: Updated Code**

```
var PostKey: String?
var geoFire: GeoFire?
var regionQuery: GFRegionQuery?
var foundQuery: GFCircleQuery?
var geoFireRef: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    geoFireRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(uid)
    geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: geoFireRef)

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    let currentUserLocation = userLocation

    let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: currentUserLocation, withRadius: 100.0)
    _ = circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
        self.PostKey = key
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    })
}

 fileprivate func fetchPostsWithUser(user: User) {

    guard let key = PostKey else { return }

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(user.uid).child(key)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        var post = Post(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
        post.id = key

        self.posts.append(post)
        self.posts.sort(by: { (post1, post2) -> Bool in
            return post1.creationDate.compare(post2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
        })
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}

fileprivate func fetchPostUserIds() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let userIdKey = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        userIdKey.forEach({ (key, value) in
            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in
                self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
            })
        })

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? It is really unclear

Comment: @J.Doe Only the current users post is being fetched. Not all the users like I want.

Comment: Hi Cody, now that you have added the `userIDKey.forEach` and are iterating through the snapshot of the `users` reference, are you still having the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to debug and look what you got in the snapshot in your function, and also what fetchUserWithUID return

```
fileprivate func fetchPostUserIds() {

     let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard let userIdKey = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

            userIdKey.forEach({ (key, value) in
            Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: key, completion: { (user) in
                self.fetchPostsWithUser(user: user)
            })
        })

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

}
```

Maybe with some more information I can help you

Comment: When I print the `Key` from `userIdKey.forEach` I get all user Id's

Comment: Okay so it works good and it takes different user in the next step right?

Answer (score 1):

You pass paremeter `user: User` to method `fetchPostsWithUser`, but you always use the current user

```
guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
```

also note these

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

will load every change so think about singleObserve

Comment: I change `ref.observe` to `ref.observeSingleEvent` but nothing changed. What do you suppose I change the `uid` to?